# How can I compare two version in C#?

Tags: c#, version

I am using `C#` language for compare two version. How can I compare two version? I had used below code but I am confused how it's working. When I had tried below code :

```
 var tem = "3.10.1".CompareTo("3.9.0"); // returns -1

var tem1 = "4.0.1".CompareTo("3.9.0"); // returns 1
```

I need 1 result for the tem variable also. Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: You are doing a lexical string compare, not comparing the two versions properly. Parse them into a class that knows how to compare version information.

Comment: For string compares, 10 comes before 2 because 1 is smaller than 2. Split the string into components, convert those components to numbers, then compare the numbers in each group.

Comment: maybe the [VersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-5.0)-class is what you're looking for

Comment: `int tem = Version.Parse("3.10.1").CompareTo(Version.Parse("3.9.0"));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should compare [Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=net-5.0)s, not `String`s:

```
 var tem = Version.Parse("3.10.1").CompareTo(Version.Parse("3.9.0"));

 var tem1 = Version.Parse("4.0.1").CompareTo(Version.Parse("3.9.0"));
```